# How to send Message in Telegram like HTML table

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to send a message in telegram like table structure if I use below HTML, it is not working

````
<tr>
    <th>Title1</th>
    <th>Title2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123
<td>abd</td>
</tr>
</table>```
````

Answer (score 5):

Telegram bot api does not support these tags. [Supported tags](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style)

You can use spaces or create image.

Answer (score -1):

You can't send these messages in Telegram that you used on your phone. You have to register an account with an API key to create a bot.

Telegram bot does support HTML tags, but as @PavloMaistruk said, you might have to check out what kind of tags are supported by reading the documentation.